# Installing mod_wsgi in addition to PHP

Tags: php, python, apache-2.2, mod-wsgi

I would like to use some python scripts with my PHP-based application. I don't want to install Django; just mod_wsgi, so Apache can execute my python scripts as well as the rest of my PHP site. How do I configure Apache to do this?

Comment: Agree with Jim.

Answer (score 0):

Getting Apache to use wsgi is as simple as making sure you have mod_wsgi.so availible and using a LoadModule directive.

However, you have to realize that [WSGI is not a framework](http://webpython.codepoint.net/wsgi_tutorial), and using it to write a script will not be anywhere near as simple as using php. If you don't want to use Django, I would recommend using some framework. Perhaps [Flask](http://flask.pocoo.org/)

Answer (score 0):

By following the documentation. Start with:

http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/WhereToGetHelp?tm=6